# How to resolve "Trello::Error: label not found"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trello

I am working on an application that will go through a Trello board, and for cards that don't have certain labels, like "email already sent", send an email. I have it fully functional on one board, but when I switch to different boards, I get this error:

```
E, [2021-07-26T19:10:07.774909 #313] ERROR -- : [404 POST https://api.trello.com/1/cards/60fb1d96ac68e617ff121cff/idLabels]: label not found
Trello::Error: label not found
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/ruby-trello-2.3.1/lib/trello/client.rb:99:in `invoke_verb'
```

I assumed this has something to do with the way labels are scoped to specific boards or something similar.

EDIT: this below is likely irrelevant, as @engineersmnky pointed out, but I'll leave it in for reference:

> But if you put that URL in the error just into Chrome, you get this page:

> [image: Trello 404]

> Which seems to imply a permissions issue.

I have identical API permissions for both accounts so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Here is the underlying code: I kind of scabbed it together from different contexts to avoid including irrelevant code, so hopefully it makes sense.

```
#Main flow of code
  def iterate_through_boards
    @boards = Trello::Board.all
    boards.each do |board|
      @board = board

      iterate_through_lists
    end
  end

  def iterate_through_lists
    board.lists.each do |list|

      #Ignore list_ac_campaign_id for now. It gets pulled from elsewhere
      email_sent_label = assign_sent_label(list_ac_campaign_id)
  
      cards = list.cards

      iterate_through_cards(cards, email_sent_label)
    end
  end

  def iterate_through_cards(cards, email_sent_label)
    cards.each do |card|
      next if card.card_labels.include?(email_sent_label.id)

      send_email_if_needed.(card, order_number, email_sent_label)
    end
  end

  def send_email_if_needed

     #if the email sends, then it runs this function
     attach_sent_label if send_email
  end


  
  #The code that adds the email after everything else, 
  #so that it won't run on that card again

  def attach_sent_label
    card.add_label(email_sent_label)
    #This line above triggers the error
  end



#email_sent_label is assigned by this code:

  @phase_labels = {
      p1_label: Trello::Label.find('60db99d5230c123a1ab808d0'),
      p2_label: Trello::Label.find('60e61ad78f4b51135ba0d547'),
      p3_label: Trello::Label.find('60e61ae7d76c8d0812dde650')
    }

  #list_ac_campaign_id is irrelevant, just know it helps assign email_sent_label
  def assign_sent_label(list_ac_campaign_id)
    case list_ac_campaign_id
    when 147
      phase_labels[:p1_label]
    when 146
      phase_labels[:p2_label]
    when 145
      phase_labels[:p3_label]
    end
  end
```

Like I say in my comment, the error is triggered by this line: `card.add_label(email_sent_label)`. How can I make it so that I can access and assign those labels to cards across multiple boards? Let me know if anything in there is unclear.

UPDATE: I have confirmed that it is an issue with different labels having different ID's in different boards, even if you copy them from another board. So it looks like either you would need some workaround that could target labels by name, not id, or find some way to access or duplicate labels across boards, or find some other way to make this mechanism more flexible to accommodate distinct labels per board.

Comment: *This is not an answer:* but you cannot access a POST route but just placing it in the browser as this will be a GET request (which is likely the issue you are seeing with the adorable sleeping dog).

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks. That makes sense. Probably should've realized that.